# What is the specific term for an Isosceles triangle where the legs are longer/shorter than the base?

Tags: triangles, math-history

I'm shocked that I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, but I have a situation where I have to categorize isosceles triangles by whether their legs are (individually) longer or shorter than their base. E.G. 3-3-2 vs. 3-3-4. Another way of looking at it is if the vertex angle is either less than 60°(for longer legs) or greater than 60°(for shorter legs).

I've taken to calling these "Tall" and "Wide" Isosceles respectively, but I was hoping for some official designation. Unfortunately, google only returns the elementary-level definitions of isosceles/equilateral/scalene and acute/obtuse.

However, I simply *cannot* believe that this never was considered and classified by some ancient greek philosopher, or that if their works did not survive that it wasn't later rediscovered by a renaissance mathematician. So, if the names exist, what are they?

*For extra context, this is for something I'm doing on a computer where I classify triangles by sorting the edge lengths (descending) and then compare them: if the longest two are equal it's "tall", if the shortest two are equal it's "wide"; if both wide and tall it's equilateral, if neither it's scalene.*

Comment: I know of no such names and I doubt that there are any current ones. It would be nice to resurrect ancient ones if they exist. In the meanwhile, "wide" and "tall" seem just right. (If your edge lengths are floating point, you might have to be careful about inequalities near equality.)

Comment: Maybe "obtuse isosceles" versus "acute isosceles"? I don't claim these are standard, but if someone used these terms,  I'd feel fairly confident that I understood their intent...

Comment: @paulgarrett But note that some of the «wide» isosceles triangles have no obtuse angles.

Comment: @PerManne, maybe "tending to obtuse"? :)